# How to generate sample records with fewer SQL queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In the `User` controller of my Rails app I have this action that populates a user's database with sample `people`:

```
def generate_samples
  10.times do
    p = current_user.people.create!(:first_name   => Faker::Name.first_name,
                                    :last_name    => Faker::Name.last_name,
                                    :email        => Faker::Internet.email)
    p.sample = true
    p.save
  end
  flash[:success] = "Samples generated."
  redirect_to people_path
end
```

What bothers me is that it takes Rails 83 SQL queries to generate these 10 people.

Is there a way to facilitate my code and maybe create X users with one query only?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you need to go through all the usual ActiveRecord stuff or can you use straight SQL? ActiveRecord does a lot of things behind your back that really aren't suitable to bulk data loading.

Comment: @muistooshort: I could do that but I wouldn't want too much raw SQL in my Ruby files. And I am not very experienced with SQL either. Would prefer to use Ruby here.

Comment: 10 SQL INSERTs should be pretty easy, or a single INSERT with a 10 part VALUES. You'd need to have appropriate constraints inside your database (which you really should have anyway) and you'd have to be careful about quoting or use the low level database driver interface so that you could use real placeholders in your SQL.

Comment: @muistooshort: I do not fully understand that I'm afraid. I'm still new to Rails. Can you point me to any code samples?

Answer (score 0):

Ya, you can wrap this in active record transaction to perform all your creates within a single transaction.  Something kinda like:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    10.times do
      p = current_user.people.create!(:first_name   => Faker::Name.first_name,
                                :last_name    => Faker::Name.last_name,
                                :email        => Faker::Internet.email)
      p.sample = true
      p.save
    end
  end
  rescue => e
    // throw your error and rollback
  end
```

Comment: That will still do the same number of queries. The transaction should make the INSERTs quicker as all the inserts can be persisted by the database when the transaction is committed but it won't reduce the number of times you talk to the database (it will actually add two).

Comment: @muistooshort: Correct. I just found that out myself.